# Pi-hole will not connect

Tags: raspbian-stretch, dns, pi-hole

I am trying to set up my Raspberry Pi as a DNS blocker on my network.  but whenever I try to add the ip address and password, I get the prompt "It only works with version 3." Or when I mess around with other settings, a "Cannot connect"

I verified that pi-hole API Version is 3 and using a Raspberry Pi 3B
I'm running Raspbian version 9 and updated debian version to 9.6

My raspberry pi can ping the devices on the network.
The only thing I can think of is that for my apartment complex internet, DNS server IP addresses get filled out in my internet settings and I had to use that address for DNS to allow my raspberry pi to connect outside the network.

Comment: I figured it out, I had to re-run:
"curl -L install.pi-hole.net | bash"

Comment: Feel free to expand on that solution and submit it as your own accepted answer. @Derek

Answer (score 1):

The questioner has found a solution as written in a comment:

> I figured it out, I had to re-run: "curl -L install.pi-hole.net | bash"